How to checkout TFVC repo in GitHub Actions which run on Linux?
How can we checkout TFVC repo from Azure DevOps using GitHub Actions? I want to run my job in Linux. Looks like the checkout action from GitHub doesn't support TFVC. Is there any other method to do?

This question is similar to: How to get tf.exe (TFS command line client)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Looks like that is for Windows. I’m looking specifically for Linux.

Scroll down please. There are quite a few cross platform options, like the Node.js based one.

Hi Noonenine, using the REST API Items - Get can download the TFVC repo from Azure DevOps no matter your job is in Linux or windows.

You can download the TFVC repo from Azure DevOps using the REST API Items - Get as zip and unzip it after downloading.
Here is the sample PowerShell script for your reference. You can run the PowerShell script in GitHub Action.
$PAT=""
$organization = ""
$project="testproject"
$path="$/testproject"

$Uri="https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/tfvc/items?path=$path&download=true&api-version=7.1-preview.1" 

$Authentication = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT"))
$Headers = @{
      Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $Authentication)
      Accept = 'application/zip'
      }

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri  -Headers $Headers  -OutFile ./file.zip

#unzip the files to the folder you want
unzip ./file.zip -d /destination/folder

